# entity framework core api save one to many relationship data

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm new to entity framework core. I'm trying to save data in a team and player tables, but I get a

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

error. Here is my sample code below:

Player Class

```
public class Player
{
  public int PlayerID {get;set;}
  public string PlayerName {get;set;}

  public int TeamID {get;set;}
  public Team Team {get; set;}
}
```

Team class

```
public class Team
{
  public int TeamId {get;set;}
  public string TeamName {get;set;}

  public ICollection<Player> Players {get;set;}
}
```

DBContext

```
public class SoccerDbContext: DbContext
{
  public SoccerDbContext(DbContextOptions<SoccerDbContext> options):base(options)
  {}

  public DBSet<Team> Teams {get;set;}
  public DBSet<Player> Players {get;set;}
}
```

Controller post method

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Save(Team team)
{
  Player player1 = new Player{
    PlayerName = "Steven"
  };
  Player player2 = new Player{
    PlayerName = "Frank"
  };

  team.Players.Add(player1); //This I where the error occurs
  team.Players.Add(player2);
  
  _context.Team.Add(team);
  await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

  return RedirectToAction("index");

}
```

Whenever I execute this code I receive "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" any idea? Thank you
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSL3x.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is occuring as the `Players` collection is null. You can instantiate by default as follows:

```
public class Team
{
   public int TeamId {get;set;}
   public string TeamName {get;set;}

   public ICollection<Player> Players {get;set;} = new HashSet<Player>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Players` property is `null`,

You can create it before you add

```
  team.Players = new List<Player>();
  team.Players.Add(player1);
  team.Players.Add(player2);
```

but i guess you want to add new team from somewhere so you should send the `Players`
inside you http request as you do with the team, for example

```
{
    "teamName": "MyTeam",
    "players": [
        {
            "playerName": "Steven"
        },
        {
            "playerName": "Frank"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `Team` object, you never initialize the Players collection.  Therefore, `team.Players` is null when you call the `Add()` method.

You can initialize the property like so:

```
public ICollection<Player> Players {get;} = new List<Player>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your players don't exist in the database and wont have an id until you save them before you add to your team.players list.
Perhaps try

```
_context.Players.add(player1);
_context.Players.add(player2);
_context.SaveChanges();

 team.Players.Add(player1); //This I where the error occurs
  team.Players.Add(player2);
  
  _context.Team.Add(team);
  await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

tbh im sure theres a more efficient way but this is a way around at least also yes you should initialise your list